# Characterization of primes dividing $(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$ in a [hypothetical] counterexample to Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Assume $p$ is an odd prime, and $x,y,z$ are pairwise relatively prime nonzero integers, such that $x^p+y^p+z^p=0$.

In Ribenboim's *Fermat's Last Theorem for Amateurs*, he gives a proof (p. 101) that every prime divisor of $(x^p+y^p)/(x+y)$ is congruent to $1\!\!\pmod{\!2p^2}$; by symmetry the same is true also for $(x^p+z^p)/(x+z)$ and $(y^p+z^p)/(y+z)$.

**QUESTION:** Are there similar results about the size or shape of primes dividing $(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$?

In particular, I'm interested in the following conjecture.

**CONJECTURE:** At least one of $x+y$, $x+z$, or $y+z$ must have a prime factor greater than $p$.

Comment: Since FLT is now proved to be true, the opening condition is vacuous. So any conjecture at all that you would like to make is vacuously true.

Comment: @alex.jordan: Then don’t bother commenting or answering. Thanks! (p.s. Your statement is false as written: If "any conjecture at all that [I] would like to make is vacuously true", then I conjecture that 1+1=3. And, according to your comment, it's [vacuously] true.)

Comment: Right, I'm implying any conjecture *that uses your opening assumption as the asusmption* is true. And I'm giving you an answer, so it's completely appropriate for me to post it. We already know your conjecture is true. And if someone finds some train of logic that you are more comfortable with, it's still all for nothing because *there are no integer $x,y,z$ and odd prime $p$ satisfying $x^p+y^p+z^p=0$*.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll just hope someone chooses to answer non-vacuously.

Comment: The purported proof of FLT, unfortunately, is one of the _courtroom style_ documents that are quite common these days, even in mathematics. Some people sound as if they have worked _themselves_ through this proof and have verified every single step in it. Sorry, but I don't buy it.

Comment: @HandeBruijn I haven't read Wiles' proof. I just trust the peer-review system that certified it.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case of Fermat's Theorem one can apply Sophie Germain's method to obtain factors. For example, if $2p+1$ is prime then $2p+1$ must be a factor of $(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$. Similarly, one can use other primes of  the form $np+1$.

Comment: This is a helpful hint — thank you!

Comment: I gave you the bounty because I think MSE was going to just waste it. And at least you gave a helpful answer!  =)

Comment: Many thanks Kieren! Stan

Answer (score -2):

Mod $2$, the assumption (that FLT is false) implies $x+y+z\equiv0$. Since $x,y,z$ are relatively prime, they can't all be even. So precisely two of them are odd. So at least one of the three factors in $(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$ is even. Therefore, $2$ is a prime dividing $(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$.

(But then if we remember FLT is true, we can also say $2$ does *not* divide $(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$, because there are no triples satisying $x^p+y^p+z^p=0$ in the first place.)

Comment: Ah! Okay. This will make it so much easier for the high school students I tutor to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational! Proof: “Assume $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. Then 1+1=3, and also 1+1=0. Contradiction. QED”

Comment: You don't get to do "$\sqrt{2}$ is rational$\implies 1+1=3$" unless you already have shown the statement preceding the $\implies$ symbol is false. So the analogy doesn't work. Wiles _has_ proved that $¬\text{FLT}$ is false, so my argument is valid.

Are you by chance trying to find some _other_ proof for FLT? And that is why you object to using the established result that it is true?

Comment: Other people have shown that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: Right now, I’m just trying to do what I said in the title.

Answer (score -4):

Here's an answer:

Assume $x^p+y^p+z^p=0$ for some integers $x,y,z$ and odd prime $p$. Then by Fermat's Last Theorem, we have a logical contradiction. It therefore follows that $1+1=2$, and also that $1+1=3$.

And also that $(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$ is divisible by $47$. And that all divisors of $(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$ are congruent to $1$ mod the order of the Monster group.

These are just *some* examples of  divisibility criteria on $(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$ that follow from the assumption.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand completely your point of view. You believe that once a theorem is proven, every subsequent proof by contradiction is totally vacuous (and, by implication, without merit or rigor)?

For example, the case $p=2$ of Catalan’s Conjecture was first proven by Ko Chao in 1960. Chein’s simplified proof in 1976 assumes the existence of a counterexample, and goes on to obtain a contradiction. You’re implying his proof is vacuous, and perhaps shouldn’t have been attempted or published?

Thanks for clarifying your position.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you are referencing. My "point of view" is that I am giving a clear, concise, and correct answer to the question that you asked. Moreover, a clear, concise, and correct answer that seems to have completely escaped you. But I think because I am answering the question *you actually asked* instead of the ill-defined question you *wanted* to ask, you are inappropriately down-voting it, along with giving the inappropriately rude response to my initial innocuous comment.

Comment: What "ill-defined" question do you think I wanted to ask? If you change your answer to frame the question the way you believe it should be asked, that would be very helpful — and I would upvote the answer accordingly.

Comment: As for the downvote, I was under the impression that downvotes are precisely for answers which are unhelpful. Is that not the idea? Equally so, if you feel my question is sufficiently unhelpful (or vague or whatever), you have the option of downvoting it.

Comment: Here’s a reference for the Chein proof: <http://www.jstor.org/stable/2041579>

Comment: To quote Richard Feynman: I would rather have questions that can't be answered than answers that can't be questioned.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan I think the question that you wanted to ask (since you feel this answer doesn't answer you) is looking for some sequence of logical implications that 1) pretends FLT is an open question, or is false 2) starts with your premise about $x,y,z,p$, and 3) concludes with some divisibility criterion on $(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$. What it actually asks for is just for 2) and 3). And the answer here provides several _true_, rigorously proved divisibility criteria on $(x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$. I'll give a separate answer demonstrating this.

Comment: In other words, it's some particular kind of _argument_ you are looking for, not the _result_.